# Uninstalling 'screenkey' program that doesn't appear in Software Center or Synaptic? (16.04)

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed a utility called "Screenkey" from the Ubuntu Software Center, but can't seem to uninstall it. It runs normally and its icon appears in the Launcher, but neither Software Center nor Synaptic think it's installed — they display the "Install" button instead of "Remove". I also tried `sudo apt-get remove screenkey`, but apt-get says "Package 'screenkey' is not installed".

What now? Thanks.

Comment: Try:  `sudo apt-get purge screenkey`

Comment: Same result: "Package 'screenkey' is not installed, so not removed".

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I was seeing was a phantom Unity launcher icon. The Screenkey software had, indeed, been uninstalled. I ran `locate .desktop | grep screenkey` to locate the launcher shortcut definition for Screenkey and deleted the file.